# Clarification on why there a one-to-one correspondence between $((a, b),(c, d))$ and $(a,(b, c), d)$ and tuple question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The individual elements of the $(A×B)×(C×D)$ and $A×(B×C)×D$ are "$((a, b),(c, d))$" and  "$(a,(b, c), d)$" respectively, correct? How then, do we know that the product has the same cardinality? Let's say there are five elements in sets $A, B, C$, and $D$. Does that mean there are $625$ elements in the cartesian product for both? Does that mean association doesn't matter for cardinality?

Also, since the elements themselves have multiple elements, are they called subsets? Is $((a, b),(c, d))$ called a subset as well or do we just call it an element? Also, I want to confirm my understanding is correct of tuples. The first element is a $2$-tuple (pair) and the second is a $3$-tuple (triple) because of the number of elements they have right? (Element inception? lol)

Thank you!

Comment: Your understanding of these concepts appears correct.  $((a, b), (c, d))$ is an element of $(A \times B) \times (C \times D)$.  A subset of that product would be $\{ ((a, b), (c, d)) \}$.  For future posts, please use MathJax to format mathematical expressions.  Here's a tutorial:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @RobertShore I noticed that you put {} around the element. Is it only a subset if we explicitly put the curly brackets around? Without it, it would just be considered a 2-tuple/pair element and not a subset of the set?

Comment: Yes, that was the point.  It's a set consisting (in this case) of a single element, an ordered pair of ordered pairs.  Of course, subsets can have many more than one element.